# Given a random string generator that keeps generating things in the style of unsolved number theory questions, how many would be difficult to solve

Tags: number-theory

I get it’s a weird question but hear me out. If all we had was a generator that specified a set descriptively e.g. all primes, all odd primes, etc...and then a property, e.g. the number is a sum of three other numbers such that the product is smaller than the square root of the number, I’m just making random stuff up here...how many of those problems would be difficult to trivially resolve? Let’s also say we only considered the ones where a machine verified it to be true for the first billion #’s (to weed out obviously false statements, like all primes are divisible by a product of three semiprimes)

It’s a weird question but I’m curiius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least a positive fraction of all predicates (asymptotically relative to length of expression in a given formal system) are trivially true for all natural numbers, at least a positive fraction are trivially false for all natural numbers, and at least a positive fraction are undecidable (in a formal system that has undecidable statements).  This is because for any predicate $P$, you can form "$P(n)$ and false" or "$P(n)$ or true" or "($P(n)$ and false) or $Q$", where $Q$ is a given undecidable statement.